# Python: Connected components on a sphere

Tags: python, hierarchical-clustering

I have been banging my head against this for some time now. My problem is very simple to explain:

I have data containing longitudes and latitudes. For simplicity, let us assume these are coordinates of cities. What I want is to separate these city coordinates into groups, so that all cities within a group lie within a given 'maximum distance' to it's nearest neighbour. All cities within a group must have at least one neighbour within this distance limit. The minimum distance between these separated groups is therefore greater than 'maximum distance' mentioned above.

My understanding is that this is a clustering problem (e.g. minimum spanning tree). The distance on the sphere can be calculated with the haversine distance, but I can't wrap my head around how to implement this...my restriction are that I can only use numpy, scipy, and scikit-learn.

I hope someone can help
thanks

Comment: This question is probably too broad for SO in its current form. I guess you could make an initial assignment to clusters using k-means (which both scipy and scikit-learn can do), and then iteratively shuttle points between clusters so that they satisfy your nearest neighbour criterion.

Comment: (cont) However, k-means requires you to specify the number of clusters in advance, which is inconvenient for this application, although you can always specify a high number and then merge clusters. You may have more success using a [k-d tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree). Another option is a Kohonen Neural Network, as used in the [NeuQuant](http://members.ozemail.com.au/~dekker/NEUQUANT.HTML) colour quantizer.

Comment: You may have more success in finding a suitable algorithm on Programmers Stack Exchange, but please check their [Help pages](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help) first to ensure your question is presented in an acceptable fashion.

Comment: @PM2Ring If I correctly understand the question, I don't think this could be meaningfully solved on any arbitrary set of data. Pick a city at random and add its nearest neighbour within limit. Next iteration, search both cities to see if they have any more to add. Stop once all are added within limit and jump to next city to start the next cluster. But on arbitrary data, you face the possibility of one giant cluster of everything, or you have the possibility of single-city clusters. Both defy "All cities within a group must have at least one neighbour within this distance limit"

Comment: Basically, that criteria seems to leave the problem unbound unless I've misunderstood. If all cities within a cluster had to be within the limit, then fine. But if I can jump to any city in my cluster to add another without checks on all existing cities in cluster then what stops me continuing to swallow up everything?

Comment: @roganjosh also, it's completely possible that that's the only solution. Consider a uniform distribution of cities on the sphere.

Comment: Thanks for your comments so far. @roganjosh The idea is that you can only 'jump' to a neighbouring city within a group as long as it is within the 'maximum distance'. If you have a uniform distribution across the globe where each city is very close to it's nearest neighbour, then, yes, you will swallow up everything into one group.

Comment: @roganjosh: Sure, the general problem is tricky, but that's normal for NP-complete problems. But often there are reasonable, efficient solutions for typical data sets, eg if you know the data _does_ in fact, have some clustering that fits the desired criteria.

Comment: You *could* find hot-spots on the map, and start kmeans with seeds in each spot...

Comment: @PM2Ring my comments are actually on the opposite side. The problem statement seems too simplistic to get an output of practical use, it appears to need another constraint. OP what I mean is that if I have 10 cities in a cluster already (1-10) then if there is a city close to 5 I can just add it without any consideration of 1-4, 6-10. The main aim of clustering is to group by some shared characteristic but things in your cluster need only share something with 1 other city in the cluster. If that's your intent, my initial comment is effectively pseudocode :)

Comment: @PM2Ring And actually, if that really is the intent - keep adding as long as it shares something with only 1 thing already in the category - then I think it would actually always converge on the same solution regardless of which city you start with and the order in which they are added to your clusters.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I have implemented a brute force approach to solve this. I am not 100% sure if the results are correct in all cases, though...if some of you have time to check this, it would be greatly appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# -------------------------------------------------------------------
def distance_sphere(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):

    # Calculate distance on sphere
    return np.degrees(np.arccos(np.sin(np.radians(lat1)) * np.sin(np.radians(lat2)) +
                                np.cos(np.radians(lat1)) * np.cos(np.radians(lat2)) *
                                np.cos(np.radians(lon1 - lon2))))


# -------------------------------------------------------------------
def distance_euclid(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):

    # Calculate distance
    return np.sqrt((lon1 - lon2)**2 + (lat1 - lat2)**2)


# -------------------------------------------------------------------
# Maximum allowed distance in degrees
max_distance = 10

# Generate city coordinates
lon_all = np.random.random(100) * 100
lat_all = np.random.random(100) * 100

# Start with as many groups as cities
group = np.arange(len(lon_all))

# Loop over all city coordinates
for lon, lat in zip(lon_all, lat_all):

    # Calculate distance to all other cities
    dis = distance_euclid(lon1=lon, lat1=lat, lon2=lon_all, lat2=lat_all)

    # Get index of those which are within the given limits
    idx = np.where(dis <= max_distance)[0]

    # If there is no other city, we continue
    if len(idx) == 0:
        continue

    # Set common group for all cities within the limits
    for i in idx:
        group[group == group[i]] = min(group[idx])


# Rewrite labels starting with 0
for old, new in zip(set(group), range(len(set(group)))):
    idx = [i for i, j in enumerate(group) if j == old]
    group[idx] = new


# -------------------------------------------------------------------
# Plot results
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, figsize=[10, 10])
for g, lon, lat in zip(group, lon_all, lat_all):
    ax.annotate(str(g), xy=(lon, lat), xycoords="data", size=12, ha="center", va="center")
    circ = plt.Circle((lon, lat), radius=max_distance/2, lw=0, color="gray")
    ax.add_patch(circ)
ax.set_xlim(-10, 110)
ax.set_ylim(-10, 110)
plt.show()
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Now I'm really confused :P I assume the numbers represent the cluster identity on the graph. In which case, does it visually look like the output wanted? I was actually in the process of putting together an example, but the output wouldn't look anything like that... clusters appear to terminate arbitrarily

Comment: Yes the number represents the cluster ID and this is just a very quick plot, without thinking of how to visualise the results. I have been running a few examples with different numbers and something is not quite right. If I substitute the spherical metric with a euclidean metric, a can see that either some connections are missing or some are wrong. But the general picture seems to be promising so far.

Comment: Ok, turns out I am stupid and did not see that x and y range in the plots is completely different with the above example when substituted with euclidean coordinates. When I corrected for that, everything seems to be fine. I think everything works for the given problem (and it's even quite fast as long as the number of cities does not explode)

Comment: Can you post the updated code so that we both look at the same output graph? I'm curious as to what the output looks like as I still don't think this code functions in the way I imagined the solution to the problem.

Comment: Sorry. I just discovered a bug in there...need to fix that before posting the correct code :D Problem is that upon iterating I reset some labels...

Comment: So, I have updated the code and the labels now should be correctly written. I have been running this a few times and the connections seem ok 

Answer (score 0):

From the graphical output as it stands in your answer, I believe that your clusters are being terminated prematurely. This is my approach to the problem; the code is ugly because really I just wanted to demonstrate the concept and I don't have time to think about the most elegant way to illustrate this. Also, it's not in numpy because then I could steal my old distance calculation function to save me some time. Hopefully the concept though is clear enough and you'll see how it could be made faster and cleaner e.g. not repeatedly rebuilding `available_locations` and maybe not re-scanning items in the cluster from previous iteration.

Edit: Illustrated behaviour:
1) Always converges on same solution for each `DISTANCE_CAP` regardless of all the randomisation in the initialisation and progression of the solution
2) Modifying `DISTANCE_CAP` can result in single-location clusters or a giant blob

```
import math
from random import choice, shuffle

DISTANCE_CAP = 20

def crow_flies(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
    dx1,dy1 = (lat1/180)*3.141593,(lon1/180)*3.141593
    dx2,dy2 = (lat2/180)*3.141593,(lon2/180)*3.141593
    dlat,dlon = abs(dx2-dx1),abs(dy2-dy1)
    a = (math.sin(dlat/2))**2 + (math.cos(dx1) * math.cos(dx2) 
        * (math.sin(dlon/2))**2)
    c = 2*(math.atan2(math.sqrt(a),math.sqrt(1-a))) 
    km = 6373 * c
    return km

# Aim: separate these back out
manchester = [[53.486286, -2.251476, 1],
            [53.483586, -2.254534, 2],
            [53.475158, -2.248011, 3],
            [53.397161, -2.509189, 4]]

stoke = [[53.037375, -2.262903, 5],
        [53.031031, -2.199587, 6]]

birmingham = [[52.443368, -1.975714, 7],
            [52.429641, -1.902849, 8],
            [52.483326, -1.817483, 9]]

# Mix them all together
combined_list = [item for item in manchester]
for item in stoke:
    combined_list.append(item)

for item in birmingham:
    combined_list.append(item)

shuffle(combined_list)

# Build a matrix:
matrix = {}
for item in combined_list:
    for pair_item in combined_list:
        if item[2] != pair_item[2]:
            distance = crow_flies(item[0], item[1], pair_item[0], pair_item[1])
            matrix[(item[2], pair_item[2])] = distance

# pick a random starting location
available_locations = [combined_list[x][2] for x in range(len(combined_list))]
start_loc = choice(available_locations)
available_locations = [a for a in available_locations if a != start_loc]

all_clusters = []
single_cluster = []
single_cluster.append(start_loc)

# RECURSIVELY add items to our cluster until it cannot get larger, then start a 
# new one
cluster_got_bigger = True
while available_locations:
    if cluster_got_bigger == True:
        cluster_got_bigger = False
        for loc in single_cluster:
            for item in available_locations:
                distance = matrix[(loc, item)]
                if distance < DISTANCE_CAP:
                    single_cluster.append(item)
                    available_locations = [a for a in available_locations if a != item]
                    cluster_got_bigger = True

    if cluster_got_bigger == False:
        all_clusters.append(single_cluster)
        single_cluster = []
        new_seed = choice(available_locations)
        single_cluster.append(new_seed)
        available_locations = [a for a in available_locations if a != new_seed]
        cluster_got_bigger = True

    if not available_locations:
        all_clusters.append(single_cluster)

print all_clusters
```

Comment: Hey. Thanks for your answers. I have also updated my code in my older answer and now it seems to work fine. I just forgot to update all the labels as soon as they were overwritten. I'll try your code later. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

May be my answer is too late.
But a quick solution is to construct a network data-structure from your cities and get the connected components of your graph:

- Each city is a node
- There is an edge between two cities if their inter-distance is lower than some threshold

Finally, use some python network module (i.e [NetworkX](https://networkx.org/)).

The code will be something like this:

```
import networkx as nx

graph = nx.Graph()

# Add all vertices (cities) to the graph
for i, city in enumerate(cities):
    graph.add_vertex(i)

# Add edges between cities that lie under a distance threshold
for i, city_one in enumerate(cities):
    for j, city_two in enumerate(cities):
         if j > i:
             link_exists = calculate_distance(city_one, city_two) < threshold
             if link_exists:
                 graph.add_edge(i,j)
# A list of sets, each set has the indices of cities
components = [c for c in sorted(nx.connected_components(G), reverse=False)]
```

The **calculate_distance** and **threshold** are supposed to be known, the first is a function and the second is the distance threshold.